# Trying to find the ratio of voltmeters V1/V2

Tags: circuit-analysis, voltmeter

[image]

I'm trying to find the ratio of voltmeters V1/V2. My attempt is shown below

Let's recall each resistors R and then we'll have V1 = (2R)(I) (since two resistors are in parallel). V2 = (3R/2)I (two resistors are in parallel and in series with remaining resistor)

Hence, we get the ratio 3/4. However, I believe that I've gone wrong somewhere. Could you assist me with that?

Regards

Comment: Can anyone comment on it?

Comment: The person who drew those resistors has never seen an actual schematic...

Comment: @pipe is there anything wrong with given circuit?

Comment: The circuit is fine except that there are no component designations (R1, R2, etc.) which makes it difficult to show your calculations. It has been deliberately drawn in a fashion to test your ability to unscramble it and see what is really going on.

Comment: You seem to be taking an Brazilian "vestibular" question. Am I right? If the answer is yes then It's explained why theses circuits are drawn so poorly. As far as I know the test designers are high school teachers, so they may actually have never been in touch with circuit designs properly.

Answer (score 1):

1. Ignore V1, collapse the left three resistors into one resistor.
2. Look! V2 is now measuring the potential in the middle of a voltage divider.
3. Compute the voltage between the common voltmeter node and the + battery terminal.
4. Now there's a voltage divider across the above nodes, V1 is measuring it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJcxMb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Circuit redrawn.*

See if Figure 1 helps. Update your question with any new calculations.

Tip: ignore V1 for now and calculate V2 first.

Comment: How did you redraw the circuit? I noticed that the voltmeter V2 is in parallel with only one resistor.

Comment: I used the CircuitLab schematic button on the editor toolbar. Label the nodes on your schematic a, b, c, etc. and do the same on mine and see if I've got it right. "*I noticed that the voltmeter V2 is in parallel with only one resistor.*" Same on yours.

Comment: Is the ratio I got correct?

Comment: No, your solution is not correct. I suggested that you calculate V2 first. Did you?

Comment: I couldn't calculate them.

Comment: Show your simplification of the circuit and your calculations.